# PLSQL Merge - Update while row not existing

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I  have three tables User, office and a role map. The user Id will be FK to the office table against the Office manager and office head. The role and the user Id will be mapped in the role map table as shown below.
When an office is deleted, the office table's Active  column will be updated to 'N'. 
When an office is deleted, I have to check if the office manager is present as office manager for any other office. (The same person can be manager for another market too)
If he is not, then I have to delete the entry in Role map table  by updating the Active flag to 'N'

Table User

```
User ID | User Name |
--------------------------
1       |   Mark    |

2       |   George  |

3       |   Rick    |

4       |   Alex    |
```

Table Office

```
Office ID   | Office Name   | Office Manager| Office Head   |   Active  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |   Off1        |   1           |   2           |   Y       |

2           |   Off2        |   1           |   4           |   Y       |
```

Role Map

```
User ID |   User Role       |   Active  |
---------------------------------------------
    1   |   Office Manager  |   Y       |

    2   |   Office Head     |   Y       |

    4   |   Office Head     |   Y       |
```

So in this example, If I delete Office 2, then I need to update the third entry in the role map table to the following 
The OFfice manager role map will be intact, as the same user is the manager for Off1 too.

Role Map -- After update

```
User ID |   User Role       |   Active  |
-------------------------------------------
    1   |   Office Manager  |   Y       |

    2   |   Office Head     |   Y       |

    4   |   Office Head     |   N       |
```

I am unsure how to implement this query in pl/sql. can someone please guide me here?

Comment: I think MERGE won't be useful here. I would create  a trigger to avoid manually updating every time after delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it would be safer to not use `merge` in this case. After deleting office or updating it's status to inactive
just run this `update`:

```
update role_map set active = 'N'
  where (user_role = 'Office Head' 
    and not exists (
      select 1 from office 
        where office_head = role_map.user_id and active = 'Y'))
    or (user_role = 'Office Manager' 
    and not exists (
      select 1 from office 
        where office_manager = role_map.user_id and active = 'Y'));
```

I'm not sure if table `role_map` is needed at all, probably it can be replaced with view, but maybe you store some other data.

Comment: Thank you. This is the query that I was trying to write.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already deleted the row from the OFFICE table, you can just check if the employees that exist in the OFFICE table have an active role or not and just do a simple update like this -

```
UPDATE ROLE_MAP 
   SET active='N' 
 where user_id not in 
    (SELECT office_manager from office
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT office_head from office)
```

Answer (score 1):

> PLSQL Merge - Update while row not existing

I don't think you could do an **UPDATE** using **WHEN NOT MATCHED** in a **MERGE** statement.

**To avoid doing a manual update every time after the delete**, you could create a **AFTER DELETE trigger** on `office` table such that whenever you delete a row from office table, update the `role_map` table. The update statement would look like:

```
UPDATE role_map SET active = 'N' WHERE user_id = :OLD.office_head;
```

For example, just a pseudo code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER office_trg
AFTER DELETE
   ON office
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   -- variable declarations

BEGIN

   -- check any conditions if required

   UPDATE role_map SET active = 'N' WHERE user_id = :OLD.office_head;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- exception handling

END;
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. Triggering was my first thought also (I deleted that part of answer during editing), it's kinda obvious, but I was afraid of `ORA-04091: table is mutating`. 
In trigger we have to select from `office` table on which trigger must be constructed. 
I know [workarounds](https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/mutating-tabletrigger-error-and-how-to-resolve-it/), 
but I doubt that they are safe/reliable for this particular question. Once again - sorry for bothering, I wonder about it.

Comment: @PonderStibbons I understand your concern, but I don't see any possibility of mutating error at all. You would be updating role_map table based on the old deleted record of office table. Plain and simple design. Executing the update statement manually after every delete is not a practical solution. So, I edited my answer and I think trigger would be a better fit.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am accepting the answer Ponder provided. But still  vote up for this one. Thanks again.